# Is there a way to prevent getting photos randomly on Firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have some folders on Firebase Storage. Every folder includes 1_org_zoom.jpg file. I can get those photos, but not in the right array order. I want to get those photos in an order like the photo below, but photos are shown randomly. I tried for loop and forEach, but didn't work. Is there any way to get these photos in an order?

```
  useEffect(() => {
  /* for(let i = 0; i<products.length; i++){
     const imgRef = ref(storage, imgFolderRef[i]);
     console.log(imgRef);
     getDownloadURL(imgRef)
       .then((url) => {
         console.log(url);
       })
   }
*/
   imgFolderRef.forEach((imgFolder) => {
     console.log(imgFolder);
     getDownloadURL(ref(storage, imgFolder))
       .then((url) => {
           setExArr((oldArr) => [...oldArr, url])
       })
   })
  
  }, [products]);
```

Array name is imgFolderRef.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of asynchronous functions is not to block the execution of the script so that several operations can run concurrently.
In your case `getDownloadURL` and `setExArr` are asynchronous, as a consequence you have no guaranty concerning the ordering of the images. What you can do is to explicitly sort the array:

```
setExArr((oldArr) => [...oldArr, url].sort())
```